# Trouble with UIKeyboardWillShow Notification

Tags: ios, swift3, keyboard, ios11

In my app's view I have several TextFields inside the ScrollView. I implemented the UIKeyboardWillShow/WillHide notifications. But I have some issues with it. When I tap the text field, WillShow works perfect, but after the keyboard hide and tap text field again it not works any more. I tap another text field and same issue. but after 2-3 taps on different textfield it works again and then same issue. this is my code which I use:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

the funcs:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height/2
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height/2
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I hide the keyboard when user tap anywhere in the view:

```
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I can't find what is the problem and how I can fix it. there is iOS 11.0.3 on my iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height/2
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let _ = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```